# Salesforce Community Registration via LinkedIn

Tags: community, registration, linkedin

The below article explains how community users can login via LinkedIn.
http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/sso_provider_linkedin.htm#sso_provider_linkedin

I wanted to check how does the user registration work in such cases? Is that too done via signing into your linkedin account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We checked on this and yes, we can register via LinkedIn. This works by signing into the linkedIn account.